# How to match string in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

Im just finishing my study on regex in Python, now I have ask to done and i dont now really how to do this part.

I have lines like this:

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
168.95.156.240 - stark2413 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:31 -0700] "GET /engage HTTP/2.0" 201 9645
71.172.239.195 - dooley1853 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:32 -0700] "PUT /cutting-edge HTTP/2.0" 406 24498
180.95.121.94 - mohr6893 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:34 -0700] "PATCH /extensible/reinvent HTTP/1.1" 201 27330
144.23.247.108 - auer7552 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:35 -0700] "POST /extensible/infrastructures/one-to-one/enterprise HTTP/1.1" 100 22921
2.179.103.97 - lind8584 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:36 -0700] "POST /grow/front-end/e-commerce/robust HTTP/2.0" 304 14641
241.114.184.133 - tromp8355 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:37 -0700] "GET /redefine/orchestrate HTTP/1.0" 204 29059
224.188.38.4 - keebler1423 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:40 -0700] "PUT /orchestrate/out-of-the-box/unleash/syndicate HTTP/1.1" 404 28211
94.11.36.112 - klein8508 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:41 -0700] "POST /enhance/solutions/bricks-and-clicks HTTP/1.1" 404 24768
126.196.238.197 - gusikowski9864 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:45 -0700] "DELETE /rich/reinvent HTTP/2.0" 405 7894
103.247.168.212 - medhurst2732 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:49 -0700] "HEAD /scale/global/leverage HTTP/1.0" 203 15844
57.86.153.68 - dubuque8645 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:50 -0700] "POST /innovative/roi/robust/systems HTTP/1.1" 406 29046
231.220.8.214 - luettgen1860 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:52 -0700] "HEAD /systems/sexy HTTP/1.1" 201 2578
219.133.7.154 - price5585 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:53 -0700] "GET /incubate/incubate HTTP/1.1" 201 12126
159.252.184.44 - fay7852 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:54 -0700] "GET /convergence HTTP/2.0" 404 23856
```

please help me:

1. How to find everything in the brackets 21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 without "-0700]
2. How to find this part `POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1`

The result should be look like this (lists of dict)

```
example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", 
            "user_name":"feest6811", 
            "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
            "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}
```

Comment: This sounds trivial if you are studying regexes. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expression would work in the specific case (the lines in the example have been saves in "server_log.txt"):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("([\d\.]*) - ([^ ]*) \[(.*?)\] \"([^\"]*)")

res = []
with open("server_log.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        m = pattern.findall(line.strip())
        if len(m) == 1:
            res.append(dict(zip(["host", "user_name", "time", "request"], m[0])))
```

Comment: Ok, thank a lot! Could u please show me the part witch I can use to take only this part: 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1' if I should use only re.findall.

Comment: Ok but I still dont know which part of "\[(.*?)\] \"([^\"]*)" I can use to paste in re.finall to see 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1' separetly.

Comment: You dont understand me :) I just need to takie only this one part 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1' with findall, so I am wondering how to write proper pattern

Comment: with "\"([^\"]*)" im getting: ['POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1',
 ' 302 4622\n197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] ',
 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0',

Comment: i have edit in my question

Comment: Yes because this is my whole excersie - previous I asked for only part of this... but I can't cope with all indeed.